# How to allow text input in list item using react native?

Tags: react-native, textinput, listitem

This question relates to React Native specifically the text input component. I wanted to create an app which allows users to select a number of people from their contacts and based on their selection, create a list with text input each beside them. From there, they are able to do text input and with the onChangeText function, changes the state of a particular key.

Below is the code that I have attempted. I tried to change the state of percent inside the prop which I believe is incorrect since all elements will share the same text input.

By doing so, whenever I made a text input to one field, the text input will erase subsequently.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        selected2: undefined,
        description: "",
        amount: "",
        notes: "",
        percent: {},
        selectedContacts:
            this.props.navigation.state.params.selectedContacts,
    };
}

const SelectedList = (props) => {

    const list = ({ allContacts }) => {
        if (allContacts) {
            return allContacts.map((item) => {
                return (
                    <ListItem key={item.id}>
                        <Body>
                            <Text>{`${item.first_name}`}</Text>
                            <Text note>{`${item.phone_number}`}</Text>
                        </Body>
                        <Right>
                            <Item>
                                <Input
                                    placeholder="0"
                                    maxLength={3}
                                    onChangeText={(percent) => {
                                        this.setState({percent});
                                    }}
                                />
                                <Text>%</Text>
                            </Item>
                        </Right>
                    </ListItem>
                )
            })
        }
    }

    <SelectedList
        allContacts={this.state.selectedContacts}
    />
```

I hope to achieve is that after selecting the number of contacts and transferring the array data, I want the array to be printed out and the text input of each list item to be independent of each other.

Any feedback and advice are welcome and I really appreciate for you to spending time reading my query and helping me with my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think its about your logic.. something like this should work. make 'percent' type to array and in onChangeText change specific item

```
this.state = {
 ...
 percent: [],
 ...
}
...

return allContacts.map((item,index) => {
...

onChangeText={(someText) => {
  var {percent} = this.state;
  percent[index] = someText;
  this.setState({percent});
}}
```